# violin catplot with color-coded swarmplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am trying to create an axisgrid with both rows and columns used to divide my dataframe. Furthermore each axis in the grid use hues to divide the dataframe, but still this is not enough. I need to also be able to add hues to the inner swarmplot. Is there any way to do this consistently?

My best attempt is something like the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('somefile.csv')

def swarm_small(*args, **kwargs):
    return sns.swarmplot(*args, **kwargs, size=5, dodge=True)

g = sns.catplot(
    x="nb_filters_0",
    y="Score",
    data=df,
    col="Metric",
    hue='loss_func',
    row="Cycle",
    kind="violin",
    inner=None,
    palette=sns.color_palette("Set1"),
)

g.map_dataframe(swarm_small, x="nb_filters_0", y="Score", alpha=0.3, hue='act')
```

However, the result of this code is completely unintelligible:
[image: catplot with violin and color swarm overlay]

What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to achieve?

The end result should be similar to the image below, but with differently colored dots rather than black
[image: catplot with violin and black swarm inner]

## EDIT

Here is the dataset in question:

`df.csv`

```
,nb_filters_0,act,loss_func,Cycle,Score,Metric
0,32,swish,cat_CE,Training,0.8765937089920044,Accuracy
1,64,swish,cat_CE,Training,0.8688039183616638,Accuracy
2,32,swish,tversky_loss,Training,0.698259174823761,Accuracy
3,64,swish,tversky_loss,Training,0.7950736880302429,Accuracy
4,32,swish,cat_FL,Training,0.8331555128097534,Accuracy
5,64,swish,cat_FL,Training,0.8638719916343689,Accuracy
6,32,relu,cat_CE,Training,0.8520230650901794,Accuracy
7,64,relu,cat_CE,Training,0.8952963948249817,Accuracy
8,32,relu,tversky_loss,Training,0.7025752663612366,Accuracy
9,64,relu,tversky_loss,Training,0.7827157974243164,Accuracy
10,32,relu,cat_FL,Training,0.8294047117233276,Accuracy
11,64,relu,cat_FL,Training,0.852095901966095,Accuracy
12,32,swish,cat_CE,Training,0.8502687215805054,Accuracy
13,64,swish,cat_CE,Training,0.8697486519813538,Accuracy
14,32,swish,tversky_loss,Training,0.6427801847457886,Accuracy
15,64,swish,tversky_loss,Training,0.7923035621643066,Accuracy
16,32,swish,cat_FL,Training,0.8491067886352539,Accuracy
17,64,swish,cat_FL,Training,0.8384494185447693,Accuracy
18,32,relu,cat_CE,Training,0.8466424345970154,Accuracy
19,64,relu,cat_CE,Training,0.867074728012085,Accuracy
20,32,relu,tversky_loss,Training,0.7502149343490601,Accuracy
21,64,relu,tversky_loss,Training,0.7740712165832521,Accuracy
22,32,relu,cat_FL,Training,0.7964913249015808,Accuracy
23,64,relu,cat_FL,Training,0.8292904496192932,Accuracy
24,32,swish,cat_CE,Training,0.8586216568946838,Accuracy
25,64,swish,cat_CE,Training,0.8712390065193176,Accuracy
26,32,swish,tversky_loss,Training,0.6616958379745483,Accuracy
27,64,swish,tversky_loss,Training,0.747669517993927,Accuracy
28,32,swish,cat_FL,Training,0.8173601031303406,Accuracy
29,64,swish,cat_FL,Training,0.8551104068756104,Accuracy
30,32,relu,cat_CE,Training,0.8587247729301453,Accuracy
31,64,relu,cat_CE,Training,0.8767231702804565,Accuracy
32,32,relu,tversky_loss,Training,0.646480917930603,Accuracy
33,64,relu,tversky_loss,Training,0.7884039878845215,Accuracy
34,32,relu,cat_FL,Training,0.8235976696014404,Accuracy
35,64,relu,cat_FL,Training,0.8377344012260437,Accuracy
36,32,swish,cat_CE,Validation,0.6401047110557556,Accuracy
37,64,swish,cat_CE,Validation,0.6336396932601929,Accuracy
38,32,swish,tversky_loss,Validation,0.5975215435028076,Accuracy
39,64,swish,tversky_loss,Validation,0.6398745775222778,Accuracy
40,32,swish,cat_FL,Validation,0.6195285320281982,Accuracy
41,64,swish,cat_FL,Validation,0.6240124106407166,Accuracy
42,32,relu,cat_CE,Validation,0.6215344667434692,Accuracy
43,64,relu,cat_CE,Validation,0.6354994177818298,Accuracy
44,32,relu,tversky_loss,Validation,0.6076468229293823,Accuracy
45,64,relu,tversky_loss,Validation,0.6276207566261292,Accuracy
46,32,relu,cat_FL,Validation,0.6186338067054749,Accuracy
47,64,relu,cat_FL,Validation,0.6285740733146667,Accuracy
48,32,swish,cat_CE,Validation,0.633764386177063,Accuracy
49,64,swish,cat_CE,Validation,0.6309429407119751,Accuracy
50,32,swish,tversky_loss,Validation,0.5335019230842589,Accuracy
51,64,swish,tversky_loss,Validation,0.6061062216758728,Accuracy
52,32,swish,cat_FL,Validation,0.6340486407279968,Accuracy
53,64,swish,cat_FL,Validation,0.6088725924491882,Accuracy
54,32,relu,cat_CE,Validation,0.8922536969184875,Accuracy
55,64,relu,cat_CE,Validation,0.9081312417984008,Accuracy
56,32,relu,tversky_loss,Validation,0.7770249843597412,Accuracy
57,64,relu,tversky_loss,Validation,0.7961365580558777,Accuracy
58,32,relu,cat_FL,Validation,0.8293270468711853,Accuracy
59,64,relu,cat_FL,Validation,0.8605788946151733,Accuracy
60,32,swish,cat_CE,Validation,0.9083679914474488,Accuracy
61,64,swish,cat_CE,Validation,0.9231570959091188,Accuracy
62,32,swish,tversky_loss,Validation,0.6798871755599976,Accuracy
63,64,swish,tversky_loss,Validation,0.7721933126449585,Accuracy
64,32,swish,cat_FL,Validation,0.8365561366081238,Accuracy
65,64,swish,cat_FL,Validation,0.9076767563819884,Accuracy
66,32,relu,cat_CE,Validation,0.9083735942840576,Accuracy
67,64,relu,cat_CE,Validation,0.9186277985572816,Accuracy
68,32,relu,tversky_loss,Validation,0.6727029085159302,Accuracy
69,64,relu,tversky_loss,Validation,0.8116425871849059,Accuracy
70,32,relu,cat_FL,Validation,0.8642058372497559,Accuracy
71,64,relu,cat_FL,Validation,0.8650031089782715,Accuracy
0,32,swish,cat_CE,Training,0.6992514133453369,Jaccard1_coef
1,64,swish,cat_CE,Training,0.6838666200637817,Jaccard1_coef
2,32,swish,tversky_loss,Training,0.541182816028595,Jaccard1_coef
3,64,swish,tversky_loss,Training,0.6625087261199951,Jaccard1_coef
4,32,swish,cat_FL,Training,0.4892797768115997,Jaccard1_coef
5,64,swish,cat_FL,Training,0.538777232170105,Jaccard1_coef
6,32,relu,cat_CE,Training,0.6523236036300659,Jaccard1_coef
7,64,relu,cat_CE,Training,0.7349743843078613,Jaccard1_coef
8,32,relu,tversky_loss,Training,0.5458822846412659,Jaccard1_coef
9,64,relu,tversky_loss,Training,0.6459022164344788,Jaccard1_coef
10,32,relu,cat_FL,Training,0.483485758304596,Jaccard1_coef
11,64,relu,cat_FL,Training,0.5216267704963684,Jaccard1_coef
12,32,swish,cat_CE,Training,0.6501385569572449,Jaccard1_coef
13,64,swish,cat_CE,Training,0.6861822605133057,Jaccard1_coef
14,32,swish,tversky_loss,Training,0.4797120094299317,Jaccard1_coef
15,64,swish,tversky_loss,Training,0.6602866053581238,Jaccard1_coef
16,32,swish,cat_FL,Training,0.5129604935646057,Jaccard1_coef
17,64,swish,cat_FL,Training,0.4991211891174317,Jaccard1_coef
18,32,relu,cat_CE,Training,0.6434061527252197,Jaccard1_coef
19,64,relu,cat_CE,Training,0.6826991438865662,Jaccard1_coef
20,32,relu,tversky_loss,Training,0.6041868329048157,Jaccard1_coef
21,64,relu,tversky_loss,Training,0.635678768157959,Jaccard1_coef
22,32,relu,cat_FL,Training,0.4358433783054352,Jaccard1_coef
23,64,relu,cat_FL,Training,0.48638531565666204,Jaccard1_coef
24,32,swish,cat_CE,Training,0.6617934703826904,Jaccard1_coef
25,64,swish,cat_CE,Training,0.6894217133522034,Jaccard1_coef
26,32,swish,tversky_loss,Training,0.5005930066108704,Jaccard1_coef
27,64,swish,tversky_loss,Training,0.6017261147499084,Jaccard1_coef
28,32,swish,cat_FL,Training,0.4648773074150085,Jaccard1_coef
29,64,swish,cat_FL,Training,0.5289482474327087,Jaccard1_coef
30,32,relu,cat_CE,Training,0.6639690995216371,Jaccard1_coef
31,64,relu,cat_CE,Training,0.698374330997467,Jaccard1_coef
32,32,relu,tversky_loss,Training,0.4827720522880554,Jaccard1_coef
33,64,relu,tversky_loss,Training,0.6543636918067932,Jaccard1_coef
34,32,relu,cat_FL,Training,0.4764146208763122,Jaccard1_coef
35,64,relu,cat_FL,Training,0.4970998167991638,Jaccard1_coef
36,32,swish,cat_CE,Validation,0.44285941123962397,Jaccard1_coef
37,64,swish,cat_CE,Validation,0.4388552010059357,Jaccard1_coef
38,32,swish,tversky_loss,Validation,0.42977508902549744,Jaccard1_coef
39,64,swish,tversky_loss,Validation,0.4756670594215393,Jaccard1_coef
40,32,swish,cat_FL,Validation,0.3555472195148468,Jaccard1_coef
41,64,swish,cat_FL,Validation,0.3597340881824493,Jaccard1_coef
42,32,relu,cat_CE,Validation,0.4208705723285675,Jaccard1_coef
43,64,relu,cat_CE,Validation,0.4445495307445526,Jaccard1_coef
44,32,relu,tversky_loss,Validation,0.4412772357463837,Jaccard1_coef
45,64,relu,tversky_loss,Validation,0.4607005417346954,Jaccard1_coef
46,32,relu,cat_FL,Validation,0.3509494662284851,Jaccard1_coef
47,64,relu,cat_FL,Validation,0.3624703586101532,Jaccard1_coef
48,32,swish,cat_CE,Validation,0.4353385865688324,Jaccard1_coef
49,64,swish,cat_CE,Validation,0.44094502925872797,Jaccard1_coef
50,32,swish,tversky_loss,Validation,0.3692890405654907,Jaccard1_coef
51,64,swish,tversky_loss,Validation,0.4405812919139862,Jaccard1_coef
52,32,swish,cat_FL,Validation,0.35618722438812256,Jaccard1_coef
53,64,swish,cat_FL,Validation,0.3418772518634796,Jaccard1_coef
54,32,relu,cat_CE,Validation,0.6910256147384644,Jaccard1_coef
55,64,relu,cat_CE,Validation,0.7223582267761229,Jaccard1_coef
56,32,relu,tversky_loss,Validation,0.6390965580940247,Jaccard1_coef
57,64,relu,tversky_loss,Validation,0.6651307940483093,Jaccard1_coef
58,32,relu,cat_FL,Validation,0.4603268504142761,Jaccard1_coef
59,64,relu,cat_FL,Validation,0.5092442631721497,Jaccard1_coef
60,32,swish,cat_CE,Validation,0.7205176353454591,Jaccard1_coef
61,64,swish,cat_CE,Validation,0.7577159404754639,Jaccard1_coef
62,32,swish,tversky_loss,Validation,0.5216941833496094,Jaccard1_coef
63,64,swish,tversky_loss,Validation,0.6331548094749451,Jaccard1_coef
64,32,swish,cat_FL,Validation,0.4778961539268494,Jaccard1_coef
65,64,swish,cat_FL,Validation,0.564242959022522,Jaccard1_coef
66,32,relu,cat_CE,Validation,0.7253686785697937,Jaccard1_coef
67,64,relu,cat_CE,Validation,0.7498416900634766,Jaccard1_coef
68,32,relu,tversky_loss,Validation,0.5122449994087219,Jaccard1_coef
69,64,relu,tversky_loss,Validation,0.6864259839057922,Jaccard1_coef
70,32,relu,cat_FL,Validation,0.5021926760673523,Jaccard1_coef
71,64,relu,cat_FL,Validation,0.5110107064247131,Jaccard1_coef
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without inner:

```
g = sns.catplot(
    x="nb_filters_0",
    y="Score",
    data=df,
    col="Metric",
    hue='loss_func',
    row="Cycle",
    kind="violin",
    palette=sns.color_palette("Set1"),
)
```

If it doen'st works, please, provide some data to reproduce df

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. Removing the `inner=None` draws the default boxplot inside the violins. I have added the dataset at the end of my question.